Can $F(x)=g(f(x))$ be differentiable at $x=\alpha$ if f and g are not at $x=\alpha$
is $F(x)=g(f(x))$ always non-differentiable at $x=\alpha$ if:
a) f is differentiable at $\alpha$ and g is not différentiable at $f(\alpha)$
b) f is not différentiable at $\alpha$ and g is differentiable at $f(\alpha)$
c) f is not différentiable at $\alpha$ and g is not différentiable at $f(\alpha)$
I need to prove them or find counter examples. I think maybe a and c are true, but b isn’t. For a counter example I was considering $f’(x)=g’(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ at $\alpha=0$ but I’m not sure if that actually works. I have no idea how to approach a proof of the others.

Hint for a) Think about $f(x)=x^2$ and try to find a 'special' $\alpha$.

If $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ then $f(g(0))$ is undefined.

Would this work ? $f(x) = |x|$ and $g(x) = step(x)$, where $step(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 0$, $0$ else. Then $g(f(x)) = 1$ which is differentiable at $0$ even though $f$ and $g$ are not.

@Ingix I’m guessing the special $\alpha$ is 1, or maybe 0 (if not I’m completely lost), but what would g be in this situation?

$\alpha=0$. Like $|x|$, $x^2$ has a global minumum at $0$, so if you set $f(x)=x^2$, you can make $g(f(x))$ nice and differentiable by choosing $g(x)$ 'nice' for $x \ge 0$, and non-differentiable or non-continous at the left side of $0$. It's the same idea as Zubzub's example, except I made $f(x)$ differentiable so it would fit for a).

The function $$x\mapsto\begin{cases}1&x\text{ is rational}\-1&x\text{ is irrational}\end{cases}$$ is useful for easy counter-examples here, without having any definition problems.

Chain rule applies only if both functions components are differentiable but the reverse direction of the implication is not necessarily true. As in the example of @Zubzub, step function and absolute value function are both non-differentiable at 0 but their composite is differentiable.
